# FancyZoom zooms only once

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, zooming, scriptaculous

I found this code somewhere on the Web.
It works fine, but only once.

The other time I trigger an eventListener it doesn't zoom.
Although the Zoombox appears, there is no swf there.

Here is HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>



<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/prototype.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.1/scriptaculous.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/fancyzoom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.onload = new FancyZoom('small');

</script>


</head>



<body>



<div><a href="#svo1" id="small"></a></div>



<div id="svo1">

<object id="FlashID" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="680" height="600">
<param name="movie" value="../flash/mega-svo.swf" /><!--value="../images/possible  pics/flash/svo4.swf"-->
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0" />
<!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
<param name="expressinstall" value="../../external_files/expressInstall.swf" />
<!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
<!--[if !IE]>-->
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="../flash/mega-svo.swf" width="680" height="600">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="11.0.0.0" />
  <param name="expressinstall" value="../../external_files/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
  <div>
    <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
    <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
  </div>
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
</object>
<!--<![endif]-->
</object>

</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Here is a fancyzoom.js as I downloaded it

```
Object.extend(String.prototype, {
// if a string doesn't end with str it appends it
ensureEndsWith: function(str) {
return this.endsWith(str) ? this : this + str;
},

// makes sure that string ends with px (for setting widths and heights)
px: function() {
return this.ensureEndsWith('px');
}
});

Object.extend(Number.prototype, {
// makes sure that number ends with px (for setting widths and heights)
px: function() {
return this.toString().px();
}
});

var Window = {
// returns correct dimensions for window, had issues with prototype's sometimes. this was ganked from apple.
size: function() {
    var width  = window.innerWidth || (window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.body.clientWidth);
    var height = window.innerHeight || (window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight);
    var x      = window.pageXOffset || (window.document.documentElement.scrollLeft || window.document.body.scrollLeft);
    var y      = window.pageYOffset || (window.document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.document.body.scrollTop);
    return {'width':width, 'height':height, 'x':x, 'y':y}
}
}

var FancyZoomBox = {
directory : '../images/fancyzoom',
zooming   : false,
setup     : false,

init: function(directory) {
if (FancyZoomBox.setup) return;
FancyZoomBox.setup = true;

var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(\d)+/);
if (ie) {
  var version = parseInt(ie[1]);
  Prototype.Browser['IE' + version.toString()] = true;
  Prototype.Browser.ltIE7 = (version < 7) ? true : false;
}

var html = '<div id="zoom" style="display:none;"> \
              <table id="zoom_table" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; height:100%;"> \
                <tbody> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td class="tl" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/tl.png) 0 0 no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="tm" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/tm.png) 0 0 repeat-x; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="tr" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/tr.png) 100% 0 no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                  </tr> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td class="ml" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/ml.png) 0 0 repeat-y; width:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="mm" style="background:#fff; vertical-align:top; padding:10px;"> \
                      <div id="zoom_content"> \
                      </div> \
                    </td> \
                    <td class="mr" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/mr.png) 100% 0 repeat-y;  width:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                  </tr> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td class="bl" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/bl.png) 0 100% no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="bm" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/bm.png) 0 100% repeat-x; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="br" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/br.png) 100% 100% no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                  </tr> \
                </tbody> \
              </table> \
              <a href="#" title="Close" id="zoom_close" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;"> \
                <img src="' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/closebox.png" alt="Close" style="border:none; margin:0; padding:0;" /> \
              </a> \
            </div>';

var body  = $$('body').first();
body.insert(html);

FancyZoomBox.zoom = $('zoom');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_table = $('zoom_table');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_close = $('zoom_close');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_content = $('zoom_content');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.observe('click', FancyZoomBox.hide);
FancyZoomBox.middle_row = $A([$$('td.ml'), $$('td.mm'), $$('td.mr')]).flatten();
FancyZoomBox.cells = FancyZoomBox.zoom_table.select('td');

// hide zoom if click fired is not inside zoom
$$('html').first().observe('click', function(e) {
  var click_in_zoom = e.findElement('#zoom'),
      zoom_display  = FancyZoomBox.zoom.getStyle('display');
  if (zoom_display == 'block' && !click_in_zoom) {
    FancyZoomBox.hide(e);
  }
});

// esc to close zoom box
$(document).observe('keyup', function(e) {
  var zoom_display = FancyZoomBox.zoom.getStyle('display');
  if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_ESC && zoom_display == 'block') {
    FancyZoomBox.hide(e);
  }
});

// just use gifs as ie6 and below suck
if (Prototype.Browser.ltIE7) {
  FancyZoomBox.switchBackgroundImagesTo('gif');
}    
},

show: function(e) {
e.stop();
    if (FancyZoomBox.zooming) return;
    FancyZoomBox.zooming   = true;
    var element            = e.findElement('a');
    var related_div        = element.content_div;
    var width              = (element.zoom_width || related_div.getWidth()) + 60;
    var height             = (element.zoom_height || related_div.getHeight()) + 60;
    var d                  = Window.size();
    var yOffset            = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets()[1];
    // ensure that newTop is at least 0 so it doesn't hide close button
    var newTop             = Math.max((d.height/2) - (height/2) + yOffset, 0);
    var newLeft            = (d.width/2) - (width/2);
    FancyZoomBox.curTop    = e.pointerY();
    FancyZoomBox.curLeft   = e.pointerX();
    FancyZoomBox.moveX     = -(FancyZoomBox.curLeft - newLeft);
    FancyZoomBox.moveY     = -(FancyZoomBox.curTop - newTop);
FancyZoomBox.zoom.hide().setStyle({
        position    : 'absolute',
        top             : FancyZoomBox.curTop.px(),
        left            : FancyZoomBox.curLeft.px()
    });

    new Effect.Parallel([
        new Effect.Appear(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {sync:true}),
        new Effect.Move(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {x: FancyZoomBox.moveX, y: FancyZoomBox.moveY, sync: true}),
        new Effect.Morph(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {
          style: {
            width: width.px(),
            height: height.px()
          },
            sync: true,
            beforeStart: function(effect) {
              // middle row height must be set for IE otherwise it tries to be "logical" with the height
          if (Prototype.Browser.IE) {
            FancyZoomBox.middle_row.invoke('setStyle', {height:(height-40).px()});
          }
                FancyZoomBox.fixBackgroundsForIE();
            },
            afterFinish: function(effect) {
              var related_div_childElements = related_div.childElements();
                for(var i=0; i<related_div_childElements.length; i++)
                    Element.insert(FancyZoomBox.zoom_content,related_div_childElements[i]);
                FancyZoomBox.unfixBackgroundsForIE();
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.show();
                FancyZoomBox.zooming = false;
            }
        })
    ], { duration: 0.5 });
},

hide: function(e) {
e.stop();
    if (FancyZoomBox.zooming) return;
    FancyZoomBox.zooming = true;        
    new Effect.Parallel([
        new Effect.Move(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {x: FancyZoomBox.moveX*-1, y: FancyZoomBox.moveY*-1, sync: true}),
        new Effect.Morph(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {
          style: {
            width: '1'.px(),
            height: '1'.px()
          },
            sync                    : true,
            beforeStart: function(effect) {
                FancyZoomBox.fixBackgroundsForIE();
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.innerHTML = '';
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.hide();
            },
            afterFinish: function(effect) {
                FancyZoomBox.unfixBackgroundsForIE();
                FancyZoomBox.zooming = false;
            }
        }),
        new Effect.Fade(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {sync:true})
    ], { duration: 0.5 });
},

// switches the backgrounds of the cells and the close image to png's or gif's
// fixes ie's issues with fading and appearing transparent png's with 
// no background and ie6's craptacular handling of transparent png's
switchBackgroundImagesTo: function(to) {
FancyZoomBox.cells.each(function(td) {
  var bg = td.getStyle('background-image').gsub(/\.(png|gif|none)\)$/, '.' + to + ')');
  td.setStyle('background-image: ' + bg);
});
var close_img = FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.firstDescendant();
var new_img = close_img.readAttribute('src').gsub(/\.(png|gif|none)$/, '.' + to);
close_img.writeAttribute('src', new_img);
},

// prevents the thick black border that happens when appearing or fading png in IE
fixBackgroundsForIE: function() {
if (Prototype.Browser.IE7) { FancyZoomBox.switchBackgroundImagesTo('gif'); }
},

// swaps back to png's for prettier shadows
unfixBackgroundsForIE: function() {
if (Prototype.Browser.IE7) { FancyZoomBox.switchBackgroundImagesTo('png'); }
}
}

var FancyZoom = Class.create({
initialize: function(element) {
  this.options = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : {};
  FancyZoomBox.init();
  this.element = $(element);
    if (this.element) {
      this.element.content_div = $(this.element.readAttribute('href').gsub(/^#/, ''));
    this.element.content_div.hide();
    this.element.zoom_width = this.options.width;
    this.element.zoom_height = this.options.height;
  this.element.observe('click', FancyZoomBox.show);
    }
}
});
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears when `FancyZoomBox.hide(e);` is called `FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.innerHTML = '';` deletes a swf file.

So I put `FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.hide();` instead of `FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.innerHTML = '';`.

I also added `FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.show()` to a `FancyZoomBox.show(e);` method.

Now everything works.

Here is a corrected code.

```
Object.extend(String.prototype, {
// if a string doesn't end with str it appends it
ensureEndsWith: function(str) {
return this.endsWith(str) ? this : this + str;
},

// makes sure that string ends with px (for setting widths and heights)
px: function() {
return this.ensureEndsWith('px');
}
});

Object.extend(Number.prototype, {
// makes sure that number ends with px (for setting widths and heights)
px: function() {
return this.toString().px();
}
});

var Window = {
// returns correct dimensions for window, had issues with prototype's sometimes. this was ganked from apple.
size: function() {
    var width  = window.innerWidth || (window.document.documentElement.clientWidth || window.document.body.clientWidth);
    var height = window.innerHeight || (window.document.documentElement.clientHeight || window.document.body.clientHeight);
    var x      = window.pageXOffset || (window.document.documentElement.scrollLeft || window.document.body.scrollLeft);
    var y      = window.pageYOffset || (window.document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.document.body.scrollTop);
    return {'width':width, 'height':height, 'x':x, 'y':y}
}
}

var FancyZoomBox = {
directory : '../images/fancyzoom',
zooming   : false,
setup     : false,

init: function(directory) {
if (FancyZoomBox.setup) return;
FancyZoomBox.setup = true;

var ie = navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE\s(\d)+/);
if (ie) {
  var version = parseInt(ie[1]);
  Prototype.Browser['IE' + version.toString()] = true;
  Prototype.Browser.ltIE7 = (version < 7) ? true : false;
}

var html = '<div id="zoom" style="display:none; z-index:90;"> \
              <table id="zoom_table" style="border-collapse:collapse; width:100%; height:100%;">   \
                <tbody> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td class="tl" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/tl.png) 0 0 no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="tm" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/tm.png) 0 0 repeat-x; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="tr" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/tr.png) 100% 0 no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                  </tr> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td class="ml" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/ml.png) 0 0 repeat-y; width:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="mm" style="background:#fff; vertical-align:top; padding:10px;"> \
                      <div id="zoom_content"> \
                      </div> \
                    </td> \
                    <td class="mr" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/mr.png) 100% 0 repeat-y;  width:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                  </tr> \
                  <tr> \
                    <td class="bl" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/bl.png) 0 100% no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="bm" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/bm.png) 0 100% repeat-x; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                    <td class="br" style="background:url(' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/br.png) 100% 100% no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden;" /> \
                  </tr> \
                </tbody> \
              </table> \
              <a href="#" title="Close" id="zoom_close" style="position:absolute; top:0; right:0;"> \
                <img src="' + FancyZoomBox.directory + '/closebox.png" alt="Close" style="border:none; margin:0; padding:0;" /> \
              </a> \
            </div>';

var body  = $$('body').first();
body.insert(html);

FancyZoomBox.zoom = $('zoom');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_table = $('zoom_table');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_close = $('zoom_close');

FancyZoomBox.zoom_content = $('zoom_content');
FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.observe('click', FancyZoomBox.hide);
FancyZoomBox.middle_row = $A([$$('td.ml'), $$('td.mm'), $$('td.mr')]).flatten();
FancyZoomBox.cells = FancyZoomBox.zoom_table.select('td');

// hide zoom if click fired is not inside zoom
$$('html').first().observe('click', function(e) {
  var click_in_zoom = e.findElement('#zoom'),
      zoom_display  = FancyZoomBox.zoom.getStyle('display');
  if (zoom_display == 'block' && !click_in_zoom) {
    FancyZoomBox.hide(e);
  }
});

// esc to close zoom box
$(document).observe('keyup', function(e) {
  var zoom_display = FancyZoomBox.zoom.getStyle('display');
  if (e.keyCode == Event.KEY_ESC && zoom_display == 'block') {
    FancyZoomBox.hide(e);
  }
});

// just use gifs as ie6 and below suck
if (Prototype.Browser.ltIE7) {
  FancyZoomBox.switchBackgroundImagesTo('gif');
}    
},

show: function(e) {
e.stop();
    if (FancyZoomBox.zooming) return;
    FancyZoomBox.zooming   = true;
    var element            = e.findElement('a');
    var related_div        = element.content_div;
    var width              = (element.zoom_width || related_div.getWidth()) + 60;
    var height             = (element.zoom_height || related_div.getHeight()) + 60;
    var d                  = Window.size();
    var yOffset            = document.viewport.getScrollOffsets()[1];
    // ensure that newTop is at least 0 so it doesn't hide close button
    var newTop             = Math.max((d.height/2) - (height/2) + yOffset, 0);
    var newLeft            = (d.width/2) - (width/2);
    FancyZoomBox.curTop    = e.pointerY();
    FancyZoomBox.curLeft   = e.pointerX();
    FancyZoomBox.moveX     = -(FancyZoomBox.curLeft - newLeft);
    FancyZoomBox.moveY     = -(FancyZoomBox.curTop - newTop);
FancyZoomBox.zoom.hide().setStyle({
        position    : 'absolute',
        top             : FancyZoomBox.curTop.px(),
        left            : FancyZoomBox.curLeft.px()
    });

    new Effect.Parallel([
        new Effect.Appear(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {sync:true}),
        new Effect.Move(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {x: FancyZoomBox.moveX, y:   FancyZoomBox.moveY, sync: true}),
        new Effect.Morph(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {
          style: {
            width: width.px(),
            height: height.px()
          },
            sync: true,
            beforeStart: function(effect) {
              // middle row height must be set for IE otherwise it tries to be   "logical" with the height
          if (Prototype.Browser.IE) {
            FancyZoomBox.middle_row.invoke('setStyle', {height:(height-40).px()});
          }
                FancyZoomBox.fixBackgroundsForIE();
            },
            afterFinish: function(effect) {
              var related_div_childElements = related_div.childElements();
                for(var i=0; i<related_div_childElements.length; i++)
                  Element.insert(FancyZoomBox.zoom_content,related_div_childElements[i]);
                FancyZoomBox.unfixBackgroundsForIE();
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.show();
                FancyZoomBox.zooming = false;
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.show()
            }
        })
    ], { duration: 0.5 });
},

hide: function(e) {
e.stop();
    if (FancyZoomBox.zooming) return;
    FancyZoomBox.zooming = true;        
    new Effect.Parallel([
        new Effect.Move(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {x: FancyZoomBox.moveX*-1, y:     FancyZoomBox.moveY*-1, sync: true}),
        new Effect.Morph(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {
          style: {
            width: '1'.px(),
            height: '1'.px()
          },
            sync                    : true,
            beforeStart: function(effect) {
                FancyZoomBox.fixBackgroundsForIE();
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_content.hide();
                FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.hide();
            },
            afterFinish: function(effect) {
                FancyZoomBox.unfixBackgroundsForIE();
                FancyZoomBox.zooming = false;
            }
        }),
        new Effect.Fade(FancyZoomBox.zoom, {sync:true})
    ], { duration: 0.5 });
 },

// switches the backgrounds of the cells and the close image to png's or gif's
// fixes ie's issues with fading and appearing transparent png's with 
// no background and ie6's craptacular handling of transparent png's
switchBackgroundImagesTo: function(to) {
FancyZoomBox.cells.each(function(td) {
  var bg = td.getStyle('background-image').gsub(/\.(png|gif|none)\)$/, '.' + to + ')');
  td.setStyle('background-image: ' + bg);
});
var close_img = FancyZoomBox.zoom_close.firstDescendant();
var new_img = close_img.readAttribute('src').gsub(/\.(png|gif|none)$/, '.' + to);
close_img.writeAttribute('src', new_img);
},

// prevents the thick black border that happens when appearing or fading png in IE
fixBackgroundsForIE: function() {
if (Prototype.Browser.IE7) { FancyZoomBox.switchBackgroundImagesTo('gif'); }
},

// swaps back to png's for prettier shadows
unfixBackgroundsForIE: function() {
if (Prototype.Browser.IE7) { FancyZoomBox.switchBackgroundImagesTo('png'); }
}
}

var FancyZoom = Class.create({
initialize: function(element) {
  this.options = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : {};
  FancyZoomBox.init();
  this.element = $(element);
    if (this.element) {
      this.element.content_div = $(this.element.readAttribute('href').gsub(/^#/, ''));
    this.element.content_div.hide();
    this.element.zoom_width = this.options.width;
    this.element.zoom_height = this.options.height;
  this.element.observe('click', FancyZoomBox.show);
    }
}
});
```